# Error handling in src/groovy classes

Tags: grails, error-handling

I have implemented a simple natural language parser as part of my grails app to implement a command line interface where the user can enter commands such as 'Create a new user' and the application will carry out this task etc, I have created files such as:

```
Tokenizer.groovy
PartOfSpeechTagger.groovy
SyntacticAnalyser.groovy
SemanticAnalyser.groovy
CommandGenerator.groovy
```

whereby these are placed in `src/groovy`

Within my controller I have a `run()` method that instantiates these parser classes and calls methods within these objects, like so :

```
 def run()
    {       
        def tokenizer = new Tokenizer()
        def posTagger = new PartOfSpeechTagger()
        def syntacticAnalyser = new SyntacticAnalyser()
        def semanticAnalyser = new SemanticAnalyser()
        def commandGenerator = new CommandGenerator()

        //split command string into tokens
        def words = tokenizer.getTokens(params.command)
          def taggedWords  = posTagger.tagWords(words)
          ... and so on
     }
```

My question is I want to be able to send error messages back to the client that arise within these parser classes, e.g in `Tokenizer` if an invalid `Token` is found etc.

What is the best way for me to handle these errors, and sent them back to the broswer?

I have no previous experience in error handling at this sort of level, so any input is welcomed.

Initially I have thought of throwing a custom `InvalidTokenException` and catching it in the controller, and rendering the text to the client, but this doesnt seem right?!

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `throw` the custom exception to controller and use `render`.

```
//You can use whichever contentType you need, here I have mentioned json
render (status: HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(), contentType: "application/json" text: exception.getMessage())
```

There is one more observation I think I should share. All of the parser utility classes which you have added in `src/groovy` is good but you would end of with `n` number of instances of each for `n` number of calls from the `Controller`. For example, a single call from controller will end up creating 5 (`Tokenizer, PartOfSpeechTagger, SyntacticAnalyser, SemanticAnalyser,
CommandGenerator`) total instances of utility classes.

To optimize the above implementation, you can `service` classes for each utility. Since `service` class is by default `Singleton`. Only one instance will be created per server. So you will end up with 5 instances of the utility services throughout the application.

OR make the utility classes Singleton explicitly.

Just a thought which might be of interest for you.

Comment: Yea that is helpful thanks, there is no concurrency issues with that I presume?

Comment: No, as long as you are handling things in local scope inside methods. Using global scope in services is not much of an advice I would share.